# The WSIG GUI : JADE Agent Integration with WSIG

Tags: java, configuration, agents-jade

We have a problam in Platforme JADE  with WSIG GUI.
How to configuration WSIG on Windows with JADE and how to use it at the   `http://localhost:8080/wsig` URL. and how to change build.xml manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my problem.
And these are the steps that I have done and worked with me

> **Step 1 : donwlead jUDDI**

1. i am using  the jUDDI this  link for donwlead : [jUDDI](https://www-eu.apache.org/dist/juddi/juddi/3.3.6/)
2. and unzip and copy paste in folder C programme files.

> **Step 2 : Create environmental variables**

```
 1. CATALINA_BASE C:\Program Files (x86)\juddi-distro-3.3.6\juddi-tomcat-3.3.6

 2. CATALINA_HOME C:\Program Files (x86)\juddi-distro-3.3.6\juddi-tomcat-3.3.6
```

[image]

> **Step 3 : Go to CMD**

And type the following commands :

```
1. cd 
2. cd C:\Program Files (x86)\juddi-distro-3.3.6\juddi-tomcat-3.3.6\bin
3. catalina.bat run
```

[image]
then : 
[image]

> **Step 4 : A new window will appear**

And type the following commands :

```
   1. configtest
   2. startup.bat
```

> **Step 5 : Go to your browser**

link : `http://localhost:8080/wsig/`

[image]

> **Verify that the port:8080 is not busy**